# Laravel foreach month start from current month

Tags: php, laravel

I have some data having date field. I want to display the data starting from the current month data ...

I get the 1st record started from current month. But next month is again starting from january. I want the records like current month+1 then currentmonth+2 and so on

```
@foreach($leave_manages as $holiday)
    <tr>
        <td class="danger">{{$holiday->date->format('F')}}</td>
        <td class="warning">{{$holiday->date->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>

        <td class="danger">{{$holiday->holiday}}</td>
        <td class="info">{{$holiday->date->format('l')}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Expected Result: March, April, May, June,............., February.

Actual Result: March, January, February..........,December

Comment: Can you post where the $leave_manages variable comes from. It looks like the issue is happening when you fetch this/set this variable.

Comment: $leave_manages=Leave_manage::orderByRaw(
     "case when MONTH(date)=MONTH(CURDATE()) then MONTHNAME(date) end desc, MONTH(date) asc"
     )->get();

Comment: Please can you show the how you're defining `$leave_manages` i.e. the code in your controller and/or route

Answer (score 0):

Since don't know the full content of your database not completely sure this is what you are looking for.

Assuming leave_manages table contains all the months you can use native eloquent query to fetch the results

```
$leave_manages = Leave_manage::whereDate('holiday', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(date('Y'), 1, 1))
   ->whereDate('holiday', '<', now())
   ->orderBy('holiday', 'acs')
   ->get();

$leave_manages->concact(Leave_manage::whereDate('holiday', '>', now())
   ->whereDate('holiday', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(date('Y'), 12, 31))
   ->orderBy('holiday', 'acs')
   ->get());
```

Comment: leave_manages table has a 'date' and a 'holiday' column.. I want to display the holiday starting from the current month

Comment: thanks a lot..but january and february records are not showing.. records displayed from march to december

Comment: Try `now()->addYear()` instead of `addMonths(12)` (updated answer)

Comment: Does this go till January or still December? you can try building the date manually first try if that works (hard code 2019-03-31) then refactor it back into Carbon object once the database query is correct

Comment: it goes till december.

Comment: Does the database contain record for January / February 2020?

Comment: No No I want january february from 2019 itself...eg March 2019, April 2019..... again return back to february 2019.. for the same year only

Comment: Ok I did not get that part of the question

Comment: Updated I would create two queries combine them in a collection

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides built-in functions to get records using date functions. below code will get records from latest to older within the current year. user this

```
$leave_manages = $leave_manages = Leave_manage::whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$from = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
$to = Carbon::now()->subMonth(11)->toDateTimeString();
$data = Leave_manage::where('created_at', '>=', $to)->where('created_at', '<=', $from)
->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m') as login_month ,  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y') as login_year"))
     ->groupBy('login_month')
     ->groupBy('login_year')
     ->orderBy('login_year')
     ->orderBy('login_month')
     ->get();
```